# Python Flask - Redirect to same url using POST request with values

Tags: python, flask, redirect

Title says it all, how do I use `redirect` and `url_for` in the `Flask` library to redirect using `POST` instead of `GET` and add some values to it.

Example which doesnt work:

```py
@app.route('/',methods=('GET', 'POST'))
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return request.form['value1']+request.form['value2']
  return redirect(url_for('',value1='hello',value2='post')) #make it a post request like a form, where i get to set more values
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about returning a render_template("same_as_get.html", value = value)?

Comment: In this scenario works, but what I'm currently facing must it to redirect as a post request

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  When you use `redirect` in flask, it's issuing an [HTTP redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) which the browser receives, and then follows to the provided URL. This facility does not support forcing the browser to POST, nor should it.  Can you provide some background on why you're trying to do this, as it looks like another approach may be required unless I've missed something...

Comment: Really is a xy problem here haha. Unfortunately I cannot fully explain my problem but I solved it already without as you said, redirecting as a POST. Thanks though